# Is it possible dynamically edit field attribute values at specific df time stamps

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, time, timeslider

I working on resource deployment simulation script which works on time enabled features and network analyst.

The resource layer is point feature, each point representing a grouping of units. The count field attribute in this layer should update with time as a unit is deployed (-1) to an incident and returned to home location (+1).

Is it possible dynamically edit field attribute values at specific df time stamps

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  For a question asking about help with scripts we like to see a snippet of the code you've tried.  Can you please [edit] your question to add a code snippet, highlighting your code and clicking the **{ }** button to format it correctly.